# Create hierarchies in SSAS Cube from multiple dimensions

Tags: sql-server, ssas, hierarchy, olap-cube

I have created a SSAS cube for sales and it has a lot of Dims and i want to create hierarchy for the warehouses, My data source has two tables for warehouses one for the Classifications and another joined one for the last level of warehouses. My classification Dim has ClassificationId and Parentid and the Warehouses Dim has the WarehouseId and classificationId. i want to create a hierarchy with all level can i do that?
This's my two dimensions:
1) Classification Dim.[image]
2) Warehouse Dim [image]

As an example from pics: I want to get the levels as >> [Oteena Warehouses]>[Cairo]>[Main Website Stor] In one dimension

Comment: What do you mean by "create a hierarchy with all level"?

Comment: Yes I want to get all levels in one dimension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a hierarchy with attributes from two different dimensions.

What you can do - if the two tables have a shared Primary Key (ClassificationId?)  - you can merge these two tables or add any relevant columns you want to use as attributes in that hierarchy.
You can do that with a named calculation in the Data Source view and create a dimension from there.